# Index match match function issue

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-match

I am using INDEX MATCH MATCH to perform a matrix lookup but the following formula returns "#N/A":

```
=INDEX(Table1,match(Table2[[#Headers],[UK],Table1[Location],0),MATCH([@DATE],Table1[#Headers],0))
```

Issue seems to be that the dates in my Table1 Header row are being recognised as text. How can I get this to work?

Comment: At first glance, the first `MATCH` has too many arguments

Comment: You have too many criteria in your first MATCH, an you are missing a `]` somewhere.

Comment: could you mock up some data for each table and expected outcome?

Comment: I am wondering how you've been able to enter these formulas at all. As far as I can tell `MATCH` takes only three arguments. But your `MATCH` formulas seem to contain 4 arguments: `match(Table2[[#Headers],[UK],Table1[Location],0)`. This shouldn't give you an `#N/A` but rather an error when you try to hit enter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `]` after `[UK]`.

When you create a table the headers are changed to text.

So you need to change your search to text that matches the format:

```
=INDEX(Table1,MATCH(Table2[[#Headers],[UK]],Table1[Location],0),MATCH(TEXT([@DATE],"mm/dd/yyyy"),Table1[#Headers],0))
```

Change the `"mm/dd/yyyy"` to the format of the header cells.

Comment: Thanks for you help. this solved the problem. i have also found an alternative solution, which I have set out below: {=INDEX(Table1,MATCH(Table2[[#Headers],[UK]],Table1[Location],0),MATCH([@DATE],Value(Table1[#Headers]),0))}

Comment: Yes but that is an array formula which is slower than the regular formula. With a small table you will not see a difference but with large tables you will.